# is it possible to bind a datagrid to a object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection

I would like to  bind a DataGrid to an object, and not to a collection of objects,

My scenario is,

I have a single record with a few columns in the database that the user will keep updating,
and for UI design purposes we would like the user to update it through a DataGrid with a single row. As a work around, I created an ObserverbaleCollection and added that record,
but I would like to do it the right way so please if someone could guide me.

Thanks

p.s. 
as requested Below

here his the xaml for the datagrid i tried

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding FacilityDefaults}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price " Binding="{Binding Price,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Default Temperature" Binding="{Binding DefaultTemperature,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>`
```

Comment: these kind of "is it possible?" questions make my blood boil... [What have you Tried??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: tried binding it straight to the object,

Comment: then post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: This is a very generic question with very little detail about the problem you are trying to solve. Nearly anything is possible with programming, but is it the ideal solution? No idea. This type of question is like going to the mechanic, telling him you hear this grinding noise from under the hood, and expecting an answer on the spot.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Instead of "Is it possible..." Ask "How do I..." and post relevant code for what you have tried. If it is not possible, someone will let you know.

Comment: thanks for  suggestion Tim i will keep it for next time for now if somene could help me here not just complain abou syntex issues TX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Datagrid as an edit mechanism for a single record seems like the wrong choice in the first place.  A Datagrid is made to work with a collection of items not really a single item.  But if you insist on using it in this manner, then binding to a collection with just your one record in it is the simplest way to make it work.  A DataGrid's ItemsSource expects an IEnumerable ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)), so binding it to a single object would be awkward to say the least.